# Creating a vector<MyClass>

Tags: c++, templates, class, vector

I need to basically create a list of MyClass objects. I thought the best way of doing this would be to write `vector<MyClass> myClassList;` however when compiling I am presented with the following error

error C2065: 'MyClass' : undeclared identifier

Why is this so?
c++

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

> I need to basically create a list of myClass objects

```
error C2065: 'MyClass' : undeclared identifier
```

Well, which is it?  `myClass` or `MyClass`?

In any case, this error message means, as it says, that `MyClass` has not yet been declared.  You need to define your class before you use it.  You either haven't defined it or you've forgotten to include the right headers, or you have made some similar error.

Comment: I am an idiot... I had the class definition below the vector variable definition. I blame using C# too much